# Issue with showing images in collectionview through URL's

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm displaying 2 images in a `collectionview` using 2 URL's like so...

```
var sampleURLArray: [NSURL] = []

sampleURLArray = [NSURL(string: "http://myApp.abc.com/products/123_45_6_image_123456")!,NSURL(string: "http://myApp.abc.com/products/789_45_6_image_654321")!]
```

And I'm iterating through the URL's and assigning the images to an array like so...

```
    for imageNumber in self.sampleURLArray {

        let imageurl1 = imageNumber
        let url = imageurl1

        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url as URL)
        self.sampleImageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)
        self.arrayOfURLImages.append(self.sampleImageView.image!)
 }
```

The images are now properly shown. But I am not to  display images in such a hard-coded fashion and I have to display the images from the url's I'm getting from my `json` response which I'm doing like so...

```
      if let projectData = result["Productdata"] as? [[String:Any]] {

     let productIds = projectData.flatMap({ $0["product_id"] as? String })
     let images = projectData.flatMap({ $0["product_images"] as? [[String: Any]] }).flatMap({ $0 })
     let imageIds = images.flatMap({ $0["image"] as? String })

    self.appDelegate.commonArrForCollectionViewImgs = imageIds //I'll get each URL from self.appDelegate.commonArrForCollectionViewImgs

         }
//CommonArrForCollectionViewImgs is set as  var commonArrForCollectionViewImgs = [String]()  
       for imageNumber in self.appDelegate.commonArrForCollectionViewImgs {

       let imageurl1 = imageNumber
       let url = URL(string: imageurl1)
       print(url)
       if let dataOfUrl = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) {
       let data = dataOfUrl
       self.sampleImageView.image = UIImage(data: data)
      }

       self.arrayOfURLImages.append(self.sampleImageView.image!)


     }
```

But when this is done, the images are not shown in the `collectionview` though I am able to parse all url's properly. Also, I'm doing the json  parsing if I'm getting success in the API request. I'm not able to figure out what the issue is. Does this have to do anything with where the `collectionview` is set up...?

Comment: you can use https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Ok..but what is it basically used for...?

Comment: @User.bw you can use this library for download images Asnycnoroshly

Comment: @IOS Singh...By parsing, I do get all images properly. but when I try to load them onto my collectionview, thats when the issue arises..does the 3rd party you mentioned address this issue...?

Comment: when I try into UITableView its worked perfectly

Comment: ok..i'll check...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can see you are using the `Data(contentsOf: url!)` initializer for fetching remote resources. This method is intended to be used for local resources only. Don't be mistaken by the URL part. URL can also point to the local resources.

According to the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init)

> **Important**
>
> Don't use this synchronous method to request network-based URLs. For network-based URLs, this method can block the current thread for tens of seconds on a slow network, resulting in a poor user experience, and in iOS, may cause your app to be terminated.
>
> Instead, for non-file URLs, consider using the 
>   `dataTask(with:completionHandler:)` method of the **NSURLSession** class. See [URL Session Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/URLLoadingSystem.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000165i) for details.

However, if you really wish to use this method you can fetch your resources like this.

```
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async
    {
        for url in urls {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!)
            self.images.append(UIImage(data: data!)!)

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.collectionView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But apart from poor user experience does it cause images to not show up entirely on the collection view...?

Comment: No apart from that the image should be displayed properly. But using this method you won't be notified about any network conditions which may influence the image loading. If they don't appear, please check if you can display them in the browser. Don't you need to include any authentication headers to be able to access them?

Comment: you mean the parameters that are to be passed while making the request..?

Comment: Yes. I don't know the specifics of your backend. If it requires authentication it may also require passing auth token when fetching resources. The easiest check is to try the URL from the browser. If the browser will load the image it's not the case.

Comment: Yes...the image is shown when loaded in the browser...Also a couple of parameters related to images are 'limit' and 'page' which is the number of images to be shown and the total number of pages. But I don't think they have anything to do with the images not being shown...

Comment: I created a sample project with collection view and remote images and everything works. Could you please post the code where you configure the collection view? Maybe you have to call `collectionView.reloadData()` after all?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155426/discussion-between-kamil-szostakowski-and-user-bw).